# Django QuerySet evaluation on accessing elements via []

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_cats(self): 
    CatFactory.create_batch(2)
    cats = Cat.objects.all()
    self.assertNotEqual(cats[0], cats[1])
```

Why does this test case pass? Is this one of the cases when Django QuerySets get evaluated (iteration, slicing, etc.)?

Comment: `cats[0]` and `cats[1]` will both make a query to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this one of the cases when Django QuerySets get evaluated (iteration, slicing, etc.)?

Subscripting a queryset with an integer (so not a slice) will force evaluation. If the queryset is not yet evaluated, it will make a query for that specific element. So in MySQL for example it will make two queries that look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM cat
LIMT 1
OFFSET 0
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM cat
LIMT 1
OFFSET 1
```

By default two `Model` objects are considered to be the same given that the two items are from the same model, and have the same primary key.

The above is however not very safe, since a database does not guarantee any order. If the database is modified in between the two queries, then it might happen that the same `Cat` is returned. You might want to add a `.order_by('pk')` here.

It might be better to evaluate through slicing however, like:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_cats(self): 
    CatFactory.create_batch(2)
    cat0, cat1 = Cat.objects.all()[:2]
    self.assertNotEqual(cat0, cat1)
```

Comment: Additional thanks for mentioning that it's not safe as the order is not guaranteed. I've already come across this, when the above test failed telling me `cats[0]` and `cats[1]` are the same `Cat`. However, there even were no database modifications in between.